# Javascript multi-dimensionally array through eval()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to access the variable FR[0]. The variable country is "FR". I thought this would do it:

```
console.log("eval country: " + eval("country"));
console.log("fr0: " + FR[0]);
 console.log("eval country0: " + eval("country")[0];
```

The output is:

```
  eval country: FR
     fr0: http://www.example.co.uk/
    eval country0: F
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: the clarify: the country variable changes. Sometimes it is FR sometimes it is UK etc etc. I want to it access the appropriate variable based on the string that country contains.

Comment: #1 [Don't use `eval()` needlessly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (this is one of those times). #2, what do `FR` and `country` look like?

Comment: `eval(country)` would do that, however you could simply do `country = FR` so theres no need to use evil eval at all

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. What's the expected output here? Seems like it's doing what it should.

Answer (score 1):

I think to answer your specific question, you'd have to do something like:

```
eval(country + '[0]')
```

But this is terrible practice because if the string was some malicious JS, then it would be evaluated and bad things would/could happen.  It would be better to just have an object store that data instead of having them in separate variables:

```
var myData = {
  "FR": ['http://example.co.fr', 'adf', 'asdf'],
  "UK": ['http://example.co.uk', 'asdf', 'asdf']
};
```

and access it like this:

```
myData[country][0]
```